# How to crop image before uploading the profile picture in react native?

Tags: react-native, cropimage.net

I need to crop the selected image or the photo took from the camera in react native before uploading it to the back end.

Answer (score 0):

You can install sharp and then:

```
sharp(originalImage).extract({ width: 1920, height: 1080, left: 60, top: 40 }).toFile("outputImage")
    .then(function(new_file_info) {
        console.log("Image cropped and saved");
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("An error occured");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) is the library you should use

iOS/Android image picker with support for camera, video, configurable compression, multiple images and cropping